# Telegram bot reply a chatid if user send command

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to make a telegram bot that can reply/return a chatid if my users send the command /myid. What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Command Handler which gets the chat_id from the payload, and send it back as response.

```
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("myid", myid_command_handler))

def myid_command_handler(update, context):
 """Send back the chat_id"""
 chat_id = update.message.chat.id 
 update.message.reply_text('Here it is: ' + str(chat_id))
```